# SharedPreferences not working as expected

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I got some troubles with a `SharedPreferences`. It looks like they are not shared trough my different activities (for example my preferences are saved in my `PreferencesActivity` but not available from my other activities)

Here is the code for my PrefencesActivity :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Creating the ActionBar
            ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // Getting the preferences
            SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFile", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("PreferencesFiles");
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

The preferences.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="Informations utilisateur">

        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="id_utilisateur"
                android:title="Identifiant"
                android:summary="Votre identifiant Hangin\'Around"
                android:dialogTitle="Identifiant Hangin\'Around :" />

        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="mdp_utilisateur"
                android:title="Mot de passe"
                android:summary="Votre mot de passe sur Hangin\'Around"
                android:dialogTitle="Mot de passe Hangin\'Around :" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="Alerte de chute">
        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="num_contact"
                android:title="Numéro à contacter"
                android:summary="Le numéro auquel un SMS sera envoyé en cas de chute"
                android:dialogTitle="Numéro à contacter en cas de chute :" />

        <EditTextPreference
                android:key="nom"
                android:title="Nom présenté"
                android:summary="Le nom auquel vous serez présenté à votre contact"
                android:dialogTitle="Nom présenté :" />

        <CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="confirm"
                android:title="Confirmation de le chute"
                android:summary="Affichera un message vous demandant de confirmer l'envoi d'un message d'alerte de chute" />
     </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="Gestion des modèles de mouvement">

        <PreferenceScreen
                android:title="Enregistrer un nouveau modèle">
            <intent android:action=".EnregistrementActivity"/>
        </PreferenceScreen>

        <PreferenceScreen
                android:title="Gérer les modèles de mouvement">
            <intent android:action=".GestionModelesActivity"/>
        </PreferenceScreen>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And here's how I get the preferences in my activities :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //creating the activity and stuffs

    // Getting my preferences
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFile", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    numContact = preferences.getString("num_contact", null);
    nomUser = preferences.getString("nom", null);
    confirm = preferences.getBoolean("confirm", false);
    modeleChute = preferences.getString("modele_chute", null);

    Log.d(TAG, "numContact = " + numContact + " - nomUser = " + nomUser + " - modeleChute = " + modeleChute);
}
```

And the log shows (modeleChute comes from another activity) :

```
01-14 17:04:40.444: D/MainActivity(13277): numContact = null - nomUser = null - modeleChute = Immobile
```

Am I doing something wrong ? (I guess so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PreferencesFile", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

update: The reason is the default implementation of the xml preferences will save to your defaultSharedPreferences rather than the one you defined. You can use 
 [setDefaultValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) to change the default if its really needed.

Comment: why does it work, btw ? shouldn't getSharedPreferences(String, int) give you a choice as to the name of the prefs, so you can have several ?

Comment: thanks. i'd have though `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName` was sufficient. the documentation is not explicit on this point